# Не работает свойство в SASS

Tags: sass, gulp-sass

Нужно для класса **footer__phone** установить **font-size: 14px**

Не могу разобраться с отступами, чтобы данный класс заработал в SASS.

**HTML**

```
<div class="footer__block">
<span class="footer__label">Наши контакты</span>
<ul class="footer__links">
<li class="footer__phone"><a href="tel:+00000000000">+0 (000) 000 00 00</a></li>
<li><a href="mailto:info@info.ru">info@info.ru</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**SASS**

```
.footer
background: #f2f5f9
padding: 40px 0px 40px 0px
&__container
    display: grid
    grid-template-columns: 256px 1fr
    grid-gap: 8rem
    &--copy
        display: flex
        justify-content: flex-end
        align-items: center
&__name
    filter: grayscale(255)
    &:hover
        filter: grayscale(0)
&__main
    display: flex
    flex-direction: column
    align-items: flex-start
&__logo
    margin-bottom: 32px
    img
        width: 225px
&__messengers
    margin-bottom: 24px
&__copy
    margin-top: 24px
    span
        display: flex
        font-size: 12px
        line-height: 16px
        color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.32)
&__blocks
    display: grid
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, auto)
    grid-gap: 32px
    align-items: start
    justify-content: space-between
&__block
    display: grid
    grid-gap: 24px
&__label
    font-size: 20px
    line-height: 24px
    color: #000
    font-weight: 600
&__links
    display: grid
    grid-gap: 8px
    color: #666666
    li
        &.current-menu-item
            a
                color: #5AAFFF
        a, button
            // color: rgba(255, 255, 255)
            display: flex
            transition: color 0.3s
            &:hover
                color: #5AAFFF
```

Свойства для класса **footer__phone** должно идти после класса **&__links**

Подскажите пожалуйста как добавить свойства для класса **footer__phone**

Comment: Смущает. что свойства background и padding у класса footer не имеют отступа вправо касательно класса. А с ними и всё остальное не имеет отступа. Это так код вставился в снипет или у вас и в проекте также?

Comment: Код так вставился в снипет. В проекте все с отступами.

Comment: > Свойства для класса footer__phone должно идти после класса &__links
Не вполне понимаю, зачем вам именно такой порядок. Если класс `footer__phone` не является встроенным в `footer__link`, и разместить его можно выше или ниже на том же уровне, как и прочие классы. Зачем такие сложности? При компиляции sass -> css описания всё-равно могут и будут меняться местами, особенно, если в разных местах будут похожие касакады.